# how to exclude last column from highchart from table

Tags: highcharts

I have a table and i am using highcharts from table to make highchart but I want its last column to be exculded from the highchart because it has some string value and highchart doesnt accept string value...

My table is like this

```
<p>column-A     Clolumn-B     Column-C     Column-D </p><br>
  abc           2              4          edit<br>
  xyz           3              3          edit<br>
  pqr           5              6          edit<br>
```

I want this column-D to be excluded from highchart as it will contain string value and highchart doesnt support string value.....

Comment: The online documentation doesn't seem to cover the data/table options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [data.src.js](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js) you have a description of options. So you can use startColumn / endColumn parameter in data object.

```
data: {
        table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
        startColumn:0,
        endColumn:2
},
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cpv4betn/